# Attach workflow email alert with Case

Tags: workflow, case, email-alert

I have a workflow to send email alert with custom template to the contact once case is created. I need to keep track of all these outgoing emails in some way, for instance - attaching it to the Case. Please provider your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What's your workflow criteria?

Comment: When a record is created.

Comment: @Sethuraman.AR You can go with custom coding. Lets say you create a custom object email communcation. Whenever case gets cretaed, you query template with its subject,body (tempalate variables needs to be replaced by apex code) and update this information in communication. This could be one workaround you could go with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting your hands a little dirty in code, you could set up an Inbound Email Service and set your org's Compliance BCC Email to the email service address. We recently set up something similar where we pass a reference number (equal to the record Id that generated the email) at the very bottom of the plaintext body of the email, which the Email Service then parses out. There are a couple different ways you can store these emails on the records that generated them, but for our purposes we use Enhanced Email and store the BCC-captured emails in EmailMessage records, related to the parent record that caused the email to be generated (as indicated by the reference number).

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible. A common solution is to add a task action to the workflow that is stored against the record. You could give the same subject as the email to the task created.

Comment: Thanks. How can I capture the email subject and body in task? I have custom email template that is used to send the email. It allows only to provide some static value to subject and comments when I create task action.

Comment: Can I use trigger to send email and attach the email to Case under Emails or EmailMessages?

Comment: Any updates on this??

Comment: Any updates on this??